# How to create conditional in routeconfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to rewrite URLs based on a specific condition.  I tried to add the conditional check in the routeconfig.cs and enclose the different routes.MapRoutes() methods for the URL rewrites but that doesn't work.  When accessing the website, it displays the directory, which results in an error.

Here's an example:

```
routes.MapRoute(...)

ClassA classA = new Class();
if(classA.IsThisTrue()) {
  routes.MapRoute(...)
  routes.MapRoute(...)
}

routes.MapRoute(...)
```

If I remove the conditional, it works.

Is there some other way to do that?

Comment: Can you show your code? Does it work without your condition?

Comment: How would you expect this to work?  Routes are built at app startup and are "constants".  They don't have an understanding of conditional logic once built.

Comment: 1. We don't know what your "condition" is.
2. We don't really what you've done.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev: I've updated the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use custom constraint for this:

```
public class MyCons : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        ClassA classA = new Class();
        return classA.IsThisTrue();
    }
}
```

Then use it in your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myRoute",
    // your own route 
    url: "myUrl/{myParam}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Some", action = "Index" }
    constraints: new { myParam= new MyCons() }
);
// other route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "myOtherRoute",
    // your own route 
    url: "myOtherUrl/{myParam}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" }
    constraints: new { myParam= new MyCons() }
);
```